# I am unable to set the compiler path for opencv library.

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, arm, ubuntu-14.04

I want to cross compile my C++ opencv code into ARM A8 cross compiler, I already made an cross compiling environment for it and I did changed the paths in CMake gui as well. I am easily able to run a normal C++ code into it. But when I am trying to run a code with opencv functions, I am getting the compiler path error **"fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory compilation terminated."**

I already tried some solutions from the stack overflow which was:

1. $ g++ program.cpp -o program `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`.
2. $ -I/path/to/the/folder/where/cv.h/is/.
3. $ arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o program program.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`.

Any kind of help would really be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the reported missing header includes the parent folder name.  Specify the path to that folder, not to the header.  Use your example #2 for this.

Comment: I already tried it like this. "arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o program program.cpp -I/home/kinshuk/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9/include/opencv"

Comment: I am saying to drop that last part, too.  Assuming the full path of the header is, /home/kinshuk/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp, I would specify only /home/kinshuk/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9/include